# Messages are not going to DLQ for Kafka JDBC Sink Connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have set up a Kafka JDBC sink connector which reads the messages from the topic and apply it to the MySQL table.

But there are certain messages in the table which are bad and don't abide to foreign key constraint, for example adding the address for a particular user ID in address table and if that user ID doesn't exist then it is bound to throw such exception.

But because of this, my connector fails, which I don't want. I read there is a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) functionality which puts the faulty messages in the DLQ and the connector will continue to run for the next messages. This doesn't seem to work in my case.

Here is my connector config:

```
{
    "name": "connector_name",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "connection.password": "Password",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "max.retries": "0",
        "retry.backoff.ms": "5000",
        "errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable": "true",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "errors.log.enable": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "max.poll.records": "1",
        "topics": "original_topic",
        "batch.size": "1",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "connection.user": "Username",
        "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "dlq_topic",
        "name": "connector_name",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "connection.url": "url",
        "pk.fields": "id",
        "pk.mode": "record_key"
    }
}
```

This property doesn't seem to work:

```
"errors.tolerance": "all"
```

And this is it, the exception I am getting:

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-v3-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:559)

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.sql.SQLException: Exception chain:

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

[2023-06-20 19:33:07,386] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-v3-0} Skipping offset commit, no change since last commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:427)

[2023-06-20 19:33:07,386] DEBUG WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-v3-0} Finished offset commit successfully in 0 ms for sequence number 1: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:264)

[2023-06-20 19:33:07,386] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=sink-v3-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)

.

.

at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.getAllMessagesException(JdbcSinkTask.java:190)

at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:133)
```

Comment: I believe the DLQ only catches certain exceptions that extend ConnectException class, not `java.sql` exception types

Comment: BTW I am using this confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.2

Comment: What happens when you use latest release?

Comment: It will be time consuming. I was using this for so long. And based on the documentation this version supports error tolerance and DLQ.

Comment: Time consuming in what way? You just replace `5.4.2` with `7.4.1`, for example, and everything else should continue to work (assuming JDBC connector is still installed, which was removed with `6.0` release). In other words, your config here is not stored in that image. Version upgrades are relatively seamless (minus the exclusion of pre built-in connectors). My point is that error handling may be "improved" in newer versions, despite the feature previously existing, which like I said, doesn't work for all exception types

Comment: Use `Filter` SMT to filter the event's that does not respects the constraints in your database Instead